# Debugging objects failing to finalize?

Tags: c#, debugging, finalizer

I have the follow code in my application to help me check that ViewModels are being finalized correctly:

```
#if DEBUG
    static int openViewModels = 0;

    protected AbstractViewModel()
    {
        openViewModels++;
    }

    ~AbstractViewModel()
    {
        openViewModels--;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(openViewModels);
    }
#endif
```

All viewModels in my application derive from this class. I find that over time, `openViewModels` increases, implying that some viewModels are failing to finalize.

I am having trouble working out why this is - I've stared at my code, but I can't see what is causing some objects to stay around. Is there any tools or procedures that can help me work out what is keeping these objects from being finalized?

Comment: Do your view models implement IDisposible ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, that is open to thread-race; that should be `Interlocked.Increment(ref openViewModels)` and `Interlocked.Decrement(ref openViewModels)`.

Secondly, finalization is non-deterministic. Unless you force it, which you shouldn't. You should not expect them to clean up in any particular time-scale, especially if you have a lot of memory available. Finalization is a factor of memory pressure.

Comment: Do you know if destructors get called correctly in the hierarchy chain? I would have thought that they do but [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx) states Destructors cannot be inherited or overloaded.

Comment: @Ian frankly, if it is that critical I'd say "use `IDisposable`, which uses virtual call, so will behave exactly as you want"; but AFAIK yes, you can have a finalizer at different levels; here you go: http://pastie.org/3848664

Comment: Agreed about the IDisposable pattern. I can't remember exactly why but I was asking myself the question about the finalizers myself a while ago and being that the code works a little more under the hood I wasn't sure on the behaviour. I tend to try and avoid finalizers altogether unless using Dispose.

Comment: Just up-voted your comment... I should have just tried that myself! Pastie.org looks useful :)

Answer (score 3):

Objects are not guaranteed to be finalized. If you need reliable finalization, you should implement `IDisposable`.

Comment: I implement `IDisposable` to do things like clear up event handlers. I'm not explicitly finalizing things here, if this is possible.

Comment: It is recommended to call `Dispose` in the finalizer. Thus it is not necessary to have any cleanup code here. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw.aspx for a desciption of the *Dispose Pattern*. I'm not entirely sure whether I understood you correctly though, so I'm sorry if this did not answer your question or if this wasn't one at all. :)